# GWT DateTimeFormat throws IllegalArgumentException when date value contains « Z »

Tags: gwt, timezone, illegalargumentexception

Parsing a date containing « Z » — timezone indicator — fails, even if the format is well seted. What's the problem?

The following code throws an IllegalArgumentException:

```
DateTimeFormat
.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
.parse("2010-12-06T10:26:52.011Z");
```

This one works:

```
DateTimeFormat
.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
.parse("2010-12-06T10:26:52.011");
```

Answer (score 2):

GWT doesn't understand 'Z' (for [Zulu TimeZone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) as GMT.  If you change the trailing Z in your first example to GMT it works fine.

```
if (s.endsWith("Z")) {
  //  strip off the last 'Z' and replace with GMT timezone information
  s = StringUtils.chop(s) + "GMT-00:00";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that?

Comment: Updated my answer to include a sample.